# Find non-zero weight cycle in weighted directed graph (positive weights only)

Tags: graph-theory

Given a directed graph whose edges are weighted with positive numbers, possibly zero, I need to find if the graph contains a cycle of non-zero weight. I would also like to enumerate these cycles.

Any hint what algorithm I should look for?

Comment: Are we permitted to go "backward" along an edge in the cycle? Does this make that edge's weight negative?

Comment: No.  I'm only interested in normal forward cycles where the sum of the weights along the cycle is non-zero.

Comment: So you want to identify oriented cycles in an unweighted digraph?

Answer (score 1):

First, you divide your graph into [strongly connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component), for example by Trajan's algorithm. Any cycle goes only through vertices of the same component. For each edge that connects two vertices of the same component, there exist a cycle that goes through that edge. So you only need to check whether there exist an edge with non-zero weight that connects two vertices of the same component (provided that there are no negative edges).